# How can we reprocess cosmos lease document using Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Azure Function, recently we tried to use CosmosDBTriggered Function that needs to create the lease document, we noticed that when there is something changed in the Cosmos Container, there will be a new entry added into the lease document, but we don't understand **what these items mean and how could we use it in other scenario instead just log it**. In addition, sometimes we would have an exception in the CosmosDBTriggered Function, while exception happened our function just stops itself and we're losing all changed documents in that instance, so we're thinking **if there is anyway to recapture our changed items in last triggered event by using the lease document**, but not sure what the lease document could tell us, could someone explain if that is approachable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions

> The lease container: The lease container maintains state across multiple and dynamic serverless Azure Function instances and enables dynamic scaling. This lease container can be manually or automatically created by the Azure Functions trigger for Cosmos DB. To automatically create the lease container, set the CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists flag in the configuration. Partitioned lease containers are required to have a /id partition key definition.

Going to your second question, error handling. The reference document is: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions

> The Azure Functions trigger for Cosmos DB, by default, won't retry a batch of changes if there was an unhandled exception during your code execution.

If your code throws an unhandled exception, the current batch of changes that was being processed is lost because the Function will exit and record an Error, and continue with the next batch.

> In this scenario, the best course of action is to add try/catch blocks in your code and inside the loops that might be processing the changes, to detect any failure for a particular subset of items and handle them accordingly (send them to another storage for further analysis or retry).

So, make sure you have `try/catch` blocks in your `foreach/for` statements, detect any Exception, deadletter that failed document, and continue with the next in the batch.

This approach is common to all event-based Function triggers, like Event Hub. For reference: https://hackernoon.com/reliable-event-processing-in-azure-functions-37054dc2d0fc

If you want to reset a Cosmos DB Trigger to go back and replay the documents from the start, after already having the Trigger working for some time, you need to:

1. Stop your Azure function if it is currently running.
2. Delete the documents in the lease collection (or delete and re-create the lease collection so it is empty)
3. Set the `StartFromBeginning` CosmosDBTrigger attribute in your function to true.
4. Restart the Azure function. It will now read and process all changes from the beginning.